# Amazon ECHO API for php

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am new to Amazon ECHO . Is there any API or code for connect this device with my core PHP project.

I have googled, but didn't get anything useful thing.
Please do needful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has not been a popular language for Alexa development. But, since Alexa skills are implemented as REST APIs, you can develop a skill in any language that can service a REST endpoint, it is possible to do so.

I remember someone posting to the dev forum about a PHP framework. I did a search there and found [92 hits](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/search.html?f=&type=question%20OR%20kbentry&redirect=search%2Fsearch&sort=relevance&q=PHP). I thought one of the posted a project, so a little more searching and found the project [here](https://github.com/MiniCodeMonkey/amazon-alexa-php).

Comment: Thank you for your reply  , I have found one URL for the php and I have created one developer account as per that URL but now I am stuck at creating Intent Schema, All I found on google are Intent Schema for static data, but i want to create dynamic Intent Schema , for eg. I want to make DB connection , and fetch answer of particular question from my DB . Any idea  for the same ?

Comment: That's a different question. I thought it had been asked here before, but I don't see it. It's certainly been asked many times on the developer forum. Short answer: you can't. It's a quality thing. One of several long answers: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/29595/why-doesnt-echo-support-ad-hoc-requests.html#answer-29623

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply .

Comment: i would like to add some light on this discussion, as per your last  ping , whatever i came to know is , we can't create dynamic Intent schema . i .e. we can't call any external API for fetching records from DB  for particular question. (Please correct me if still i am on wrong direction for the same ) , but i found Amazon echo for Uber ( online transportation network company ). so, in this what 's the scenario behind this   ? , Any idea ? Thanks in advance . find this link : 

https://medium.com/uber-developers/alexa-your-uber-is-arriving-now-45567f602bdf#.cgxpi14ws